# Easiest way to group and count in SQL

Tags: sql

Question: Show all of the patients grouped into weight groups.
Show the total amount of patients in each weight group.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN weight >=0 and weight <=10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patients_in_group1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN weight >=11 and weight <=20 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patients_in_group2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN weight >=21 and weight <=30 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patients_in_group3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN weight >=31 and weight <=500 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS patients_in_group4
FROM patients
```

Comment: What are your dbms `mysql<>` `postgresql`? I remove tags both of them

Comment: It appears you want to `group by` a `case` expression so you get the results in rows.

Comment: change count() to SUM()